# Trying to preg_split uppercases and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to learn regex and get an array of words / numbers from these possible strings:

```
String: 'getUser100Profile'
Return: array('get', 'user', '100', 'profile')

String: 'put100'
Return: array('put', '100')

String: 'post'
Return: array('post')
```

Here is my snippet which is not working:

```
$name = 'get100';
$names = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z\d+])/', $name);

Return: array('get', '1', '0', '0');
Should return: array('get', '100');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the precedent character. You can use this pattern:

```
$names = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/', $name);
```

Comment: Note that for `yesIAm` this will give you: `yes`, `IAam`

Comment: @Qtax: there are indeed a lot of problems with this pattern, I will rewrite it.

Comment: Perfect, now 'yesIAm100testTest' returns: 'yes', 'I', 'Am', '100', 'test', 'Test'

Comment: Zero-width poetry... +1 :)